# JQUERY hover dropdown with hoverIntent

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, hoverintent

I am creating a dropdown that slides down when hovered over. This is some code that I had. I want to use HoverIntent to accomplish this goal.

.menu_img is the class on the image that is hovered over to start the slide down of the list

.page_nav is the class on the list that slides down when .menu_img is hovered over.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img.menu_img').click(function () {
   $('ul.page_nav').stop().slideDown('slow');
  });
});
```

## HTML

```
<div id="helper_bar">
    <div class="page_width">
        <img src="images/page_nav.png" alt="page_nav" title="use this to navigate the page" class="menu_img" width="179" height="33" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="page_width">
    <ul class="page_nav">
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services Offered</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">The Process</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the code that I have. This works if you click on the img but if you switch .click to .hover it will hover out when you try to go to the li's. This is why I brought in hoverIntent plugin but I'm not sure how to integrate it to get the proper solution I'm trying to create.

BTW i didn't include the HTML code but its a simple image and ul li tags which I know are working fine. There is a display: none; on the ul li and I did some stuff to make it funciton properly in my layout. (i have the layout a bit different than a regular dropdown.) Either way, I'm very certain my CSS is right, I just need to figure out how to write the Jquery. Thanks!

Comment: @Bob, are they both in a single container?

Comment: they are not in a container. Just inside of body. The reasoning is the helper_bar extends 100% of the screen width 

and the page_nav extends from directly under it.

But they are in seperate things. The class="page_width" div sets a width of 940px, and aligns it to the center. So it wraps the page_nav to accomodate my dimensions for content. I hope I am making sense. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: it makes sense! I updated my answer with an more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Updated Answer]**

What you want to do is going to be a bit challenging with a hover effect. Here is a possible solution, but you can't use `hoverIntent` with it because it needs the events to bubble, and `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events don't bubble. However, I have incorporated a hoverIntent-like effect in this solution. First wrap both items in a single div with the id of `menu`:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="helper_bar"> ... </div>
    <div class="page_width"> ... </div>
</div>
```

And use this JS (inside a document.ready event):

```
var trigger = $("img.menu_img")[0], // The DOM element
    $nav    = $("ul.page_nav");     // The jQuery Wrapped DOM element
$("#menu").mouseover(function(e){
   // Keep track when the mouse is over the menu area
   if(e.target == this){
     $(this).data('over', true);
   }      

   // Only show menu if the img.menu_img was what triggered the event
   if(e.target == trigger){
     $nav.stop().slideDown('slow');
   }
}).mouseout(function(e){
   if( e.target == this ){
       var $this = $(this);
       $this.data('over', false);
       window.setTimeout(function(){
          if(!$this.data('over')) $nav.stop().slideUp('slow');
       }, 500); // Wait half a second to see if the mouse reenters the element
   }
});
```

Please ask if you have questions or problems with this solution.

**[Original Answer]**

`hover` will never work for what you want, since the `ul` list can never be a child of an `img`. Every time you move off the `img` the menu will hide. What I would recommend, is something like this (Actually, I would recommend you use image replacement instead of an image, but lets just do one thing at a time):

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><img class="menu_img" alt="Home" />
      <ul class="page_nav">
         ...
      </ul>
  </li>
  ....
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$("#nav > li").hoverIntent( function(){
    $('ul.page_nav', this).stop().slideDown('slow');
}, function(){
    $('ul.page_nav', this).slideUp('slow');
});
```

This way the `mouseenter` event (or a delayed version of it with hoverIntent) fires when the `li` is hovered, and won't fire again until the entire list is exited by the mouse. So, as long as the mouse is over the `li` or any of its children, the `mouseout` event will never fire, allowing the `page_nav` to do its job as a menu.

Comment: Hello Doug, Thanks for that response. The problem is in my design I have a button to activate the slide down and its located in the middle of a width: 100%; bar of some height. Currently, the dropdown comes out from behind the bar (simulated effect, really it just slides open and is positioned directly under the bar). Because of this my image is in the div containing the bar and my ul li is outside of that div (of the bar). I updated my original post with the HTML code.

Comment: Doug, I really appreciate this. I have put it in as specified and tried it. It slides down properly but it does not mouseout properly. It just stays stuck open. I ran it in firebug console to see if there were any errors and they didn't show. Not exactly sure what is going on yet but I am going to look through this and try to figure it out too. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Bob, I am glad it got you going in the right direction. Try removing the timeout and the `!$this.data('over')` as you try to isolate the problem. I'll check back tomorrow (going to bed now) to see if you leave any more questions or comments. Cheers man!